# Send message to certain channels in certain time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is what i have tried so far.

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
    const moment = require('moment');
    const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

    var job = new CronJob({
        // cronTime: '00 03 00 * * 1-7', // 00:03:00
        cronTime: '* * * * *', //every minute
        onTick: function() {
            console.log(moment.tz('Europe/London').format('HH:mm:ss'))
            createShop()
        },
        start: false,
        timeZone: 'Europe/London'
    });
    job.start();

    function sss() {
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0x8644ba)
        .setDescription('test')
        bot.channels.find('topic', 'test').send(embed)
    }
});
```

but bot sending message only in one guild even if i have 3 guilds with channel what have 'test' topic

Comment: So you have more than one channel with the topic `'test'`?

Answer (score 0):

You only get one channel because [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) only returns the first one. To get them all, use [`Collection.findAll()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=findAll)

Here is an example:

```
function sss() {
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(0x8644ba)
    .setDescription('test');
  let results = bot.channels.findAll('topic', 'test'); //returns an array
  for (let channel of results) channel.send(embed);
}
```